# Showing a messagebox from library

Tags: qt, qmessagebox, qapplication

I need to show a messagebox to user from my static library but using `QMessageBox` needs `QApplication`;

How can I show a message box without `QApplication`?

Comment: A raw call to [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx), perhaps? You don't need to fill in the owner window.

Comment: @RadLexus: I need a cross platform messagebox,  MessageBox is windows specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just instantiate an instance of `QApplication` for the lifetime of the app.  (e.g. in your "main", "WinMain", or somewhere early in your app initialization sequence)

From then on, you can create modal instances of `QMessageBox` all you want.  It should co-exist fine with your own message pump as long as you are using a recent version of Qt.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Hello World");
    msgBox.exec();  // blocks until the user finishes interacting with the message box

    return 0;
}
```